# Covariance of random sums

Tags: covariance

How can I compute
$$cov(\sum^N a_k,\sum^{N'}a_k)$$
where $N$, $N'$ are **random dependent variables** and $a_k$ iid random variables , as a function of (but not necessarily)  cov(N,N'), $var(N)$, $var(N')$, $var(a_k)$ and all of their expectation value ?

$N$ and  $N'$ are bounded and positive.

My best shot :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    cov(X,Y)&=cov(\sum^Na_k,\sum^{N'}a_k)\\
    &=cov(\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N}a_k,\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N'}a_k)\\
    &=cov(\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N}a_k,\sum\mathbb{1}_{k<N'}a_k)\\
    &=\sum\sum cov(\mathbb{1}_{k<N}a_k,\mathbb{1}_{k'<N'}a_{k'})\\
    &=\sum\sum \mathbb{1}_{k<N\cap k'<N'}cov(a_k,a_{k'})\\
    &=\sum \mathbb{1}_{k<\min(N,N')}var (a_k)\\
    &=\min(N,N')var(a)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Feels wrong, is the 4th step right ? I use bilinearity on infinite sums, moreover if $N$ and $N'$ were constants the same method would have worked so...

Thank you

Comment: So the number of summands is random? In any case, you might want to take advantage of the fact (or better yet, prove to yourself) that the covariance is a bilinear map.

Comment: the number of summand is random, yes. Because that is the case, I do not believe I can use bilinearity straightforwardly as is usually done @Galen

Comment: I am just fiddling with it on paper here. I think you can do it, but you'll need to be familiar with sigma notation (hint: what is $\left(\Sigma^n a_i \right) \left( \Sigma^m b_j \right)$?).

Comment: We can assume that $N$ and $N^{\prime}$ are finite? I would assume so, otherwise why bother with $\text{Cov}(N, N^{\prime})$?

Comment: N and N' are finite and strictly positive, it's $\sum^n_i\sum^{n'}_j a_i b_j$

Comment: Is $a_k$ independent of $N$, and $N^{\prime}$?

Comment: Yes they are independent

Comment: Your idea looks sound, but you made a mistake with the fifth equal sign: when you take the indicator functions out of the covariance, the result is suddenly random (since $N$ and $N'$ are random).  This cannot be right, since the left-hand side is not random.

Comment: Yes indeed @jochen, I realized my mistake too, I left it so that people can "learn" from it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Law of total covariance (wiki) [helps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance) here. What you found is when $N$ and $N'$ are given:

$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y|N,N')=\operatorname{var}(a)\min(N,N')$$

$$\mathbb E[X|N,N']=N\mathbb E[a], \ \ E[Y|N,N']=N'\mathbb E[a]$$

Plugging in gives us:
$$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=\operatorname{var}(a)\mathbb E[\min(N,N')]+\mathbb E[a]^2\operatorname{cov}(N,N')$$

I'm not sure how you can simplify the expected value of the minimum.

Comment: Thanks @gunes, i found the same thing but 3 hours too late !